# How to create recurring weekly job in Azure Scheduler programmatically

Tags: azure, azure-scheduler

I'm using Microsoft Azure Scheduler Management Library (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Scheduler/) to schedule jobs in Azure Scheduler. So far, creating jobs by minute, hours and days is working fine.

My question is how to schedule a **weekly** job with specified days of the week. The code below results in exception with message "BadRequest: Cannot set days of month with recurrence unit 'Week'.".  I can't see where I'm setting "days of month" as described in the exception. The Days collection is described as the "Days of the week that the job should execute on".

```
var result = _azureSchedulerClient.Jobs.CreateOrUpdate("My Job", new JobCreateOrUpdateParameters()
{
    Action = _azureSchedulerJobAction,
    StartTime = startDateTime,
    Recurrence = new JobRecurrence()
    {
        Frequency = JobRecurrenceFrequency.Week,
        Interval = 1,
        EndTime = new DateTime(2014, 12, 31);
        Schedule = new JobRecurrenceSchedule()
        {
            Days = new List<JobScheduleDay> { JobScheduleDay.Monday }
        }
    }
});
```

Has anyone been able to get a weekly schedule working? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try this:

```
JobCreateOrUpdateResponse jobResp = schedClient.Jobs.CreateOrUpdate("testRecurrenceIssue", new JobCreateOrUpdateParameters
            {
                Action = new JobAction
                {
                    Request = new JobHttpRequest { Uri = new Uri("http://www.bing.com"), Method = "GET" },
                },

                Recurrence = new JobRecurrence
                {
                    Frequency = JobRecurrenceFrequency.Week,
                    Schedule = new JobRecurrenceSchedule
                    {
                        Days = new List<JobScheduleDay> { JobScheduleDay.Monday},
                        Hours = null,
                        Minutes = null,
                        MonthDays = null,
                        MonthlyOccurrences = null,
                        Months = null
                    }
                }
            });
```